# procrustes alternative

Tags: bootstrap, permutation-test, multidimensional-scaling, exchangeability, procrustes-analysis

Im comparing two multidimensional MDS solutions, the solutions have the same number of dimensions. I don't think I can use the permutation version of procrustes analysis (commonly, PROTEST in R::vegan) because I doubt my two sets are exchangeable. I read that the sets must have similar covariance matrices to be exchangeable, which they don't. I can also not motivate exchangeability from a design perspective, as it is not experimental, rather it is a study comparing human and model-based assessment in lower dimensional space.

My endeavor turned towards bootstrapping as it has fewer restrictions, however now I doubt I can use that as it seems to sample individual rows multiple times generates an incredible bias (procrustes of original datasets estimate of correlation is just half of the estimate from the bootstrap)

Any ideas? I'm wondering if I have to take another path entirely or if it is possible to run permutated procrustes and I'm just not knowledgeable enough.

BR,
Eric

Comment: Obviously you can just look at the solutions and compare what you see. You seem to want a significance test instead, but it isn't quite clear what the null hypothesis is you want to test. The objects in the two MDS solutions are the same? How did you generate these solutions so that they are different?

Comment: Both sets are generated from the same items, however one is human judgements of similarity, and one is algorithmic euclidian distance based on computer vision, that was then translated to mds. Want I am need is an estimate of how alike their same-dimensional solutions are and procrustes rotation seemed the obvious choice.

Comment: I haven't worked with Procrustes Analysis, but if I'm not mistaken, it will give you a measure of (dis-)similarity. Your discussion of permutation/bootstrap looks like you want a hypothesis test, but could you do without? (I'm not sure what null hypothesis you'd want to test here.)

Comment: it will, but it will also be hard to interpret unless it is placed in context, i.e. the permuted/bootstrapped versions of the procrustes estimate. The null would be that the observed similarity appeared by chance.

Comment: That's not a well specified null. What exactly does "by chance" mean? I think that this should be framed within a statistical model, but I have no idea what that could be. (But maybe it's just me and somebody else can help.)

Comment: PROTEST tests the null hypothesis that there is no association between the two data sets, if I understand things correctly. I don't think this makes sense in your case; they are obviously associated, so you won't learn anything from testing whether they're not.

Comment: Maybe it could be an interesting null hypothesis to test that human judgements of dissimilarity are equal to the algorithmic distance plus random noise, with a model for the random noise specified. This however wouldn't be very easy to test (as distances are not independent), and I also suspect that one wouldn't go via MDS and Procrustes to test this, rather I think it should be run on the raw distances/dissimilarities. If this were a consultation job I could imagine coming up with something, but it's too much for just helping on the internet.